# Write catalogue file names in to a file with additional string at the beginning end of a specific name

Tags: zsh, ls, macos

In specific directory
using `ls | tee -a file.txt`
gives me a list from this directory.

Example:

```
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt
```

How to add specific strings inside `ls` command into final output simply for batch post-processing? I need to copy and paste specific filenames with specific commands for every single file.

Example would be

```bash
ls | tee -a string1(FilenameFromDirectory)string2
```

Output

```
string1(file1.txt)string2
string1(file2.txt)string2
string1(file3.txt)string2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a string to the beginning and end is quite easy:

```
$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt
$ ls | sed -e 's/^/string1/' -e 's/$/string2/'
string1file1.txtstring2
string1file2.txtstring2
string1file3.txtstring2
```

I strongly urge you not to use parentheses `( )`. Having special characters in file names maes handling them more complicated. Use `_` or `-` instead, if you can. If you insist on parentheses, you can do this:

```
$ ls | sed -e 's/^/string1(/' -e 's/$/)string2/'
string1(file1.txt)string2
string1(file2.txt)string2
string1(file3.txt)string2
```

***Important***: this is OK if you just want to print the result in the terminal or send to a file with `>` or `tee` as you were doing. However, it is not OK if you want to use it to rename, copy or otherwise process the files because [parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) this way is very fragile and breaks with even slightly strange file names. A safer way is:

```
$ for file in *; do
   printf 'string1(%s)string2\n' "$file"
done
string1(file1.txt)string2
string1(file2.txt)string2
string1(file3.txt)string2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'string1(%s)string2\n' *
```

Would print a `string1(filename)string2` line for each of the non-hidden files in the current working directory, sorted lexically, or fail with an error if there was no matching file.

Printing nothing when there's no matching file instead of reporting an error could be done by using the `N` (nullglob) glob qualifier and check the number of files:

```
files=( *(N) )
(( $#files == 0 )) || printf 'string1(%s)string2\n' $files
```

Or using an anonymous function and the rc-style of array expansion:

```
() { print -rC1 'string1('$^files')string2'; } *(N)
```

But if you want to run some command for each file, you'd do:

```
for file (*(N)) cmd with $file as argument
```

To send the output of those commands/loops both to the original stdout and append it to some file, you can pipe them  to `tee -a some-file` or just add `>&1 >> some-file` where `zsh` doesn't an implicit builtin `tee` when output is redirected more than once.